# Python - Await Coroutine optionally without raising RuntimeWarning

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I currently have a Cache-like object that has a `aget` method, which receives the name of the object to return and the callback coroutine if the key doesn't exist.

```py
import asyncio

class Cache:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cache = {}

    async def aget(self, name, default):
        try:
            return self.cache["name"]
        except KeyError:
            return await default

async def foo():
    pass

async def bar(cache):
    obj = await cache.aget("duh", foo())
    # If "duh" doesn't exist, then await foo() and return it

cache = Cache()

asyncio.run(bar(cache))
```

So supposing that the key DOES exist, then `foo()` will never be awaited and thus raises a `RuntimeWarning` complaining about the coroutine not being scheduled.

***Question:*** Is there a *clean* way to optionally await a coroutine, without the need to unpack the coroutine and its arguments like `aget("duh", foo, arg)`. I don't consider supressing the RuntimeWarning as an option since that exist for its usecase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found myself another answer, creating tasks and cancelling them might cause cancelling issues and unnecessary overhead.

```py
    async def aget(self, name, default):
        try:
            obj = self.cache["name"]
        except KeyError:
            return await default
        else:
            default.close()
            return obj
```

For some reason the `close()` method is not documented anywhere, this is the method which the `gc` calls on coroutines objects.

**EDIT**: As comment said, it is documented on https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#coroutine-objects

Comment: FWIW, they're documented in [the language reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#coroutine-objects).

Answer (score 1):

> Question: Is there a clean way to optionally await a coroutine, without the need to unpack the coroutine and its arguments like `aget("duh", foo, arg)`.

You could create the task, but cancel it before it got the chance to even begin running:

```
    async def aget(self, name, default):
        try:
            obj = self.cache["name"]
        except KeyError:
            return await default
        else:
            asyncio.create_task(default).cancel()
            return obj
```

If you go down this road, be sure to measure the overhead of creating and canceling a task. Since it happens on the (presumably) hot path of your code, it might affect your performance.